# Get value in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

```
def bid= Book.findAllBy(params.bname)

println(bid.id)
```

I got the result `[58]`

How can I just get the value without the quote?

And how can I convert 'bid' to an Integer?

Answer (score 8):

The returned value of `findAllBy` is a list. In your case, that list contains only one `Book` instance.

Using the property operator on a list creates a new list with the corresponding properties of all list elements. So `bid.id` creates a list with the integer 58 as the single element. The `toString()` method of the list object prints this as `[58]`. In order to get the integer value you should call `bid[0].id` (although `bid.id[0]` - more wastefully - would also work in this case).

Alternatively you can call `Book.findBy(params.bname).id`. The `findBy` method only returns a single instance.

Comment: Just to clarify a technical point in the "alternative" method; `Book.findBy` will indeed return a single instance as @Ingo Kegel suggested, but it would be more appropriate to say it will return the *first* result that matches the query. Click [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html) for more info.  I would suggest that the "alternative" method is the better option here, assuming `bname` is unique.